# Is event of button which type is submit click or submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please advise which event I should write in code for of type submit. Is it click or submit. I know that submit should be put for form. If button submit put inside in form I may write

```
$('form').submit()
```

is's for case of pushing button enter on keyboard.
If push button of the form should I write in code

```
$('button[type="sumbit"]').click()
```

Comment: Buttons are clicked, forms are submitted.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here, but if you want to run some code when a form is being submit, use the form.submit event, not the button.click.

Comment: Reading you, it gives the impression that you have not tried to experiment with your hypotheses to forge your knowledge...

Comment: If you are using a button outside of a form, no need to specify the type. call on click by its ID. If it is inside a form and submitting the form, then use onsubmit().